# Read MainWindowHandle For Process

Tags: c#, wpf, adobe-reader

i tried to read MainWindowHanlde For Acrobat Reader 10 Process so i can SetParent API
i tried this

```
private Process pDocked;
private IntPtr hWndDocked;
pDocked = Process.Start(path, PDFPath);
while (hWndDocked == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    pDocked.WaitForInputIdle(1000);
    pDocked.Refresh();
    if (pDocked.HasExited)
    {
        return;
    }
    hWndDocked = pDocked.MainWindowHandle;
}
```

and the result is hWndDocked = 0
even i tried this on acrobat reader 9 and i got the MainWindowHandle but it didn't work on acrobat reader 10

please help
And Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by saying "it didn't work on AR 10" ? You weren't able to find a handle of main window or you weren't able to act on that window ?

Comment: You can't make this work reliably anymore.  Short from .NET not being able to figure out what the main window is, acrord32.exe is also a single instance application.  Your code will crash when it is already running.  That new behavior shoots a big hole in your plan to tinker with the window parent.

Comment: Hi Tigran And Thanks , i couldn't fine the MainWindowHandle , And Thanks Hans but if you say so , what is the proper way to do this , i want to dock it in my application , please help

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, and find that when the following properties are true,there is no MainWindowHandle, and if the "main form" have child window, then the MainWindowHandle of process will be the child window handle rather than the expected main window. WEIRD!!! wish I can understand why. but once I find this I solve my problem in another way (in my case I not really need the MainWindowHandle)!

When the following:

```
public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.ShowIcon = false;
        }
```

No MainWindowHandle (=0)!!

if you create sub window, in this case the MainWindowHandle of the process will be the handle of frmLogon :

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmLogon frm = new frmLogon();
            frm.Show();
        }
```

Close the frmLogon and the MainWindowHandle of the process back to zero (=0)!!

Hope this info is helpful!